# For-Loop to assign index value Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

Apologies for the naive nature of this question but I am very new to VBA.

I have a column of data with the number of pageviews a particular page has had.

I then have a seperate sheet that assigns an index value of between 1 and 30 depending whether the number of page views exceeds a specific number.

For example if a page has 10,000 page views then that is an index value of 4 as index 4 is any number over and including 8,640 and upto 10,368 where it would become index 5.

As I have many rows of data to complete this indexing on I would like to create a loop that will check what index each page should be assigned and then print the index in a new column in the same row.

I have been looking at tutorials but can't find anything specific enough to help me out. If anyone has any advice or a quick example to get me started that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You don't need VBA for this. You can use a `VLOOKUP` formula in the new column. See this [Contextures page](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2009/06/01/convert-percentages-to-letter-grades-with-vlookup/) grade range example.

Comment: Why don't you just use a vlookup? with range_lookup set to TRUE.

Comment: Thanks for these comments and the link. If however I wanted to use VBA for this is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it with VBA, although as others have mentioned its not required. 
Forget about looping, its slow and unnecessary.

```
Sub HTH()

    With Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A$1:B$5,2)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Assumes you have the index layed out like this:

```
A1      B1
1       1
5       2
500     3
8640    4
10,368  5
```

And your pageviews in column A on sheet2.